# Do while Loops not working

Tags: c++

I've been recycling an assignment to further practice and develop my programming skills in my class and I'm having an issue with 3 DO WHILE loops within another Do While loop.

I'm trying to deny Test scores for test1, 2 and 3 that are less than 1 and greater than 100. 
I'm encountering that the loops are not processing what I am inputting for Test1/2/3. It's allowing values out of the while range to pass through. Is there anyone who can suggest or see what I might be doing wrong? Thanks ahead of time guys!

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<iomanip>
    using namespace std;
    double computeavg (int a, int b, int c);
    char lettergrade (double z);

    int main ()
    {



    double test1, test2, test3, average; //test1/2/3, test scores, Average:         average of test scores
    double tottest1=0, tottest2=0, tottest3=0, avg1, avg2, avg3; //tottest# - sum of test grades collected for that number test, avg# average for first         second or third test
    int student=0, avgvar; //average variable, Student number
    char grade, ans; // Holds a letter grade, holds a response to a question

    do{
    student=student+1;
        cout<<"Hello Student #"<<student<<endl;
        do{

        cout<<"Please input test 1 Grade ";
            cin>> test1;
        }   
        while(test1>=1||test1<=100);

        do{

        cout<<"Please input test 2 Grade ";
            cin>> test2;
        }   
        while(test2>=1||test2<=100);

        do{

        cout<<"Please input test 3 Grade ";
            cin>> test3;
    }
        while(test3>=1||test3<=100);        
    average=computeavg (test1, test2, test3);

        cout<<setprecision(0)<<fixed;
        cout<<"Your Average is: "<<average<<endl;

    tottest1=tottest1+test1;
    tottest2=tottest2+test2;
    tottest3=tottest3+test3;

    grade = lettergrade(average);

        cout << "Your grade is " << grade << endl;

            cout<<"Do you want to grade another student? (y/n)";
            cin>>ans;
        cout<<"\n";
    } while(ans=='y');
```

Comment: No, the conditions are completely backwards.  If it's between 1 (why not `0`?) and 100 it's ok.  If outside that range, loop and ask again.

Comment: You realize the loop is supposed to continue (repeat) when the `while` condition is true, right?

Comment: You do realize any number will evaluate to true in the `while` condition because they are either higher than 1 or lower than 100. For example, if `test3` is 0 then it is less than 1 but it is definitely not over 100. If `test3` is 120 then it is over 100, but it is definitely more than 1. In short, it will always be true no matter what value of `test3` is. In short `true || true`, `true || false` and `false || true` are always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change do while as below:

do{

```
    cout<<"Please input test 1 Grade ";
        cin>> test1;
    }   
    while(test1<1||test1>100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are backward. Look carefully: `while(test3>=1||test3<=100)`. *All* numbers satisfy at least a portion of the condition. For example, −4 is not greater than or equal to 1, but it *is* less than or equal to 100, and since your conditions are joined with the `||` operator, which is the *or* operator, the condition evaluates to true.

You need to change the condition. This is homework, so I won't tell you precisely what condition you should use instead.

You can use a debugger to discover this problem yourself. You can also discover it by carefully walking through your program by hand. Get a pencil and some paper, and write down the current values of your variables. Keep track of which instruction you're on, and then work your way through the program. When a variable changes, cross out its old value and write down the new one. Eventually, you'll be able to do that in your head, but while you're learning, it helps to just write it down.